# Possible solutions instead of 12 relays

Tags: arduino, switches, relay, solid-state-relay

First of all i am new to electronics, but have some basic idea.

I want to create a USB switcher with arduino, which will control "where" the usb device is plugged in, instead of unplugging and plugging manually from one device to another, there will be the usb cables connected to 3 devices and the usb device connected to one port on the switcher.

With my current knowledge, since usb has 4 wires, and I want the device to be connected to 3 devices I need either a manual 4pole toggle switch with On-On-On states or 12 relays (3 relays for each wire - turning on 4 relays at a time for a certain device)

There must be another simpler solution, maybe a 4 pole 3 throw relay - does it exist? as I couldnt find.

EDIT : some type of transistors ?

Comment: USB switches are available commercially.

Comment: Yes but not controlled from my own web interface or android app. I want the usb switcher to be part of my current project. :)

Comment: You could connect all the USB grounds together and provide your own 5V to the switched device, then you'd only have to switch the 2 data lines.

Comment: Is your device separately powered, or does it require power at all times from one of the USB ports?  What about the grounds?  Are all the hosts on the same ground?  Is it OK to short all these grounds together at your device?

Comment: What is the nature of the USB device that is being shared, and why does it make sense to share it in this way, as opposed to, say, connecting it to one host and sharing it via the LAN?

Comment: You could improve this question by dropping the ambiguous word 'device' and saying clearly whether you mean 'host' or 'peripheral' - it's clear from the comments that people are confused what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the 4 wires is ground, and you almost certainly don't need to switch this - you can just connect them all together.

One of the 4 wires is power - if you're connecting to multiple hosts, then you definitely shouldn't connect them all together, but you could use some simple p-channel MOSFET switch to switch between the channels.

The other two lines are data, and particularly if you're trying to get high-speed USB to work, then they need some care.  You might use three two-pole signal relays, but that's probably questionable for high-speed.

There are ICs designed specifically for switching USB - for example:

http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NLAS7222A

here's a three-way one:

http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NCN1154

But it's in a package which you will struggle to deal with without a PCB and some reasonable soldering kit/skills - at least it gives you an idea of the sort of thing to look for.

As with all hobby-projects, the 'best' solution is some intersection of your technical abilities, budget, facilities, etc.

Don't bother looking for a triple-throw relay though...

Answer (score 0):

As USB features quite high frequencies, you have to be careful about added capacitance and board layout I'd say. (Sorry my experience ends somewhere in the 20MHz region)

For the purpose of switching the lines, there are ICs available to switch the data lines (search for USB multiplexer). With these you should have less trouble meeting the requirements on resistance and capacitance as they are specifically designed to do this.

For the power lines you might want to use something like MOSFETs which can handle the current.

For ground I'd guess you would connect them all together, but that might not be a good choice.

If you need galvanic isolation these suggestions are rather useless.